# Google App maker user picker validation

Tags: google-app-maker

In App maker user picker widget is populating the users added in the organization.
But it is not throwing any error when a valid value is not entered in the field. It just saves as an empty field.
How to use the Validation display and Validation error message when an error encountered. I want display different error message when a particular error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can enforce it on Model level by making the field required. Secondary, you can add your custom validation logic on UI:

```js
// UserPicker onValidate event
if (widget.value === null || widget.value === '') {
  return 'validation error message goes here';
}
```

Be sure, that your form's submit button is bound to `@widget.parent.parent.valid` (it is default App Maker binding for forms) or forces validation on click:

```js
// submit button onClick event for AM auto-generated form
if (widget.parent.parent.validate()) {
  widget.datasource.createItem();
}
```

This will trigger `onValidate` event for the UserPicker widget.

Comment: It is working, but some times while editing the record if we clear the value from picker field error is not throwing Instead it saves the record.

Comment: Most likely UserPicker 'remembers' your original choice and doesn't reset value to null when you clear textbox. I thought that this bug was fixed... You can report it again: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410

Comment: Kind of works, you still can type anything without selecting actual account and after submitting a form no value will be stored.

Comment: Even if the onValidate script works correctly and even if the validationDisplay option is checked, I noticed that the User Picker does not show error messages. Also, when you select one of the suggested users the onValidate script is not executed, so it is difficult to set subsequent actions based on the validity of the widget. To solve the second problem I have to call the method validate when the value changes (onValueChange).